# How can I identify what type of parabolic function this LED is pulsing at?

Tags: functions

I have a hardware device with a LED that fades between bright and dark once about every 2.4 seconds. I want to figure out what function is used to create its pattern.

I have taken a video of the LED pulsing and then use linux tools `ffmpeg` and `imagemagick` to extract brightness values and plot them on a graph. ([Raw data](https://github.com/spuder/MuteMe-arduino/files/9334885/foobar.txt) for anyone curious).

[image]

At this point I'm at a loss of how to further identify this function. I've tried plotting popular functions from this [incredible article](https://makersportal.com/blog/2020/3/27/simple-breathing-led-in-arduino) into wolfram alpha.

I suspect it may be a gaussian function like: `e^sin(x)` [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Esin%28x%29).

I am researching Fourier Transforms on youtube, but my inexperience is preventing me from seeing how to apply that to this wave form.

I am very inexperienced and I graciously would like advice from anyone with ideas. What tools and techniques could I use to more precisely identify this function?

[image]

---

### Additional resources

- [Popular Arduino LED Library that implements e^sin(x)](https://github.com/SethSenpai/singleLEDLibrary/blob/master/singleLEDLibrary.cpp#L108-L112)
- [Reverse engineering apple 'breathing' glow](https://avital.ca/notes/a-closer-look-at-apples-breathing-light)
- [Another Arduino LED Library that implements e^sin(x)](https://github.com/marmilicious/FastLED_examples/blob/master/breath_effect_v2.ino#L51)

Comment: It's probably not actually any particular simple mathematical function.

Comment: It looks quite a lot like the triangular one ... Or maybe there is a slight deceleration at each peak, so maybe slightly sinusoid. If one analyzes the actual data captured, we might be able to determine a better candidate. Sure Fourier transforms could be used as well, but that might not always provide the simplest solution as it points to a sum of trigonometric-functions.

Comment: I have a theory that the deceleration at the peak is the camera sensor automatically adjusting exposure.

Comment: This formula is really really close `period ((exp(sin(x/1205* pi))-1/e+55)*(200/(e-1/e)))`